# How to move slides in javascript in a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I have the following code in javascript to move my slides:

```
var slider = {


  el: {
    slider: $("#slider"),
    allSlides: $(".slide"),
    sliderNav: $(".slider-nav"),
    allNavButtons: $(".slider-nav > a")
  },

  timing: 300,
  slideWidth: 100% 


  init: function() {
    this.bindUIEvents();
  },

  bindUIEvents: function() {

    this.el.slider.on("scroll", function(event) {
      slider.moveSlidePosition(event);
    });

    this.el.sliderNav.on("click", "a", function(event) {
      slider.handleNavClick(event, this);
    });

  },

  moveSlidePosition: function(event) {
    // Magic Numbers =(
    this.el.allSlides.css({
      "background-position": $(event.target).scrollLeft()/6-100+ "px 0"
    });  
  },

  handleNavClick: function(event, el) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var position = $(el).attr("href").split("-").pop();

    this.el.slider.animate({
      scrollLeft: position * this.slideWidth
    }, this.timing);

    this.changeActiveNav(el);
  },

  changeActiveNav: function(el) {
    this.el.allNavButtons.removeClass("active");
    $(el).addClass("active");
  }

};

slider.init();
```

I get no error in the console regarding this but the slides should move after every 3 seconds automatically, they are not doing it now. Does anyone know whats the problem here. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a JSfiddle with a proper example, that'll help figure the issue out.

Comment: I can't see the interval definition.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax issue with a percent it must be a string and have the comma following to not break your object.

Should this line `slideWidth: 100%` be `slideWidth: "100%" ,`